# eslint error in html file: Parsing error: Unexpected token <

Tags: html, eslint

why eslint give me this error
Parsing error: Unexpected token <  in html file?
how can i solve this error?
my .eslint.json configs:

```js
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "es2021": true
        },
    "extends": [
        "airbnb-base"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 12
    },
    "rules": {
        "strict": "off"
    }
}
```

Comment: Where can the .eslint.json file be found for global setting?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you need `eslint-plugin-html` to lint html file. the details can be found in this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-html

Answer (score 6):

Adding the below to ".eslintrc.json" file worked for me:

```
"ignorePatterns": [
  "**/*.html"
]
```

Comment: This solution it's a workaround to prevent eslint validation in your html file(s). The better solution is to add a propper plugin such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-html

Answer (score 0):

One other option can be to add an `.eslintignore`file. See the exmple below.

.eslintignore

```
.vscode/*
dist/*
assets/*
node_modules/*
**/index.html
**/index.*.html
**/assets/*.html
```

Comment: This is equivalent to "fixing" a compiler error by saying "Don't compile your code, your error won't reappear."

Comment: @F-H -->  and true